# Linq InsertOnSubmit, DeleteOnSubmit and update not working

Tags: linq, insertonsubmit

I read a couple of posts related to InsertOnSubmit is not working but none of them resolve my issue. Below is my code, I have insert manually a record in my BackupPlan table and when i run a linq select the record from database and the 2 new records I tried to insert below returned and show in log, but when I checked in server explorer -> data connections -> table BackupPlan only the record that was manually inserted was there and not the new ones. I also tried updating existing record and delete with no success and without getting any exception. Furthermore I have added a column Id and set as a primary key to my BackupPlan table, checked db.GetChangeSet() and returns that 2 insert statements are pending, but db.SubmitChanges() runs after with no success. Any idea what I am missing here??? :(

```
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace Storage.Models
{
    [Table(Name = "BackupPlan")]
    public class BackupPlan
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int Id;

        [Column]
        public string Name;

        [Column]
        public string Description;
    }
}

using System.Data.Linq;
using Storage.Models;

namespace Storage
{
    public partial class Repository : DataContext
    {
        public Table<BackupPlan> BackupPlans;
        public Repository(string connection):base(connection){}
    }
}

using System;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using Storage.Models;
using Storage.Properties;

namespace Storage
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {                
                var settings = new Settings();
                var db = new Repository(settings.DatabaseConnectionString)
                             {Log = Console.Out, ObjectTrackingEnabled = true};                


                var backupPlan1 = new BackupPlan() {Description = "This is my first backup plan!", Name = "B Plan"};                
                db.BackupPlans.InsertOnSubmit(backupPlan1);                

                var backupPlan2 = new BackupPlan() {Description = "This is my first backup plan 2!", Name = "B22 Plan"};
                db.BackupPlans.InsertOnSubmit(backupPlan2);

                var t = db.GetChangeSet(); //shows that 2 inserts are pending

                db.SubmitChanges();   // when i run this method i check my table but there are no any new records                         

                var q = from b in db.BackupPlans
                        select b;
                foreach (var backupPlan in q)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", backupPlan.Name);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();              
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: Here is my config file with the connection string                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Storage.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf"
            providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: For such a basic question I would expect that someone can help but :(

Answer (score 0):

http://dean-o.blogspot.com/2010/03/mind-your-copy-to-output-directory.html

You build your program, it copies the database file to Bin/Debug and you write to that copy.

The next time you build, it's going to overwrite the database you just wrote to with a fresh copy. Change it to do not copy.